# Django model blank=True, but sql always NOT NULL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am building a Django website from a tutorial. The model is called Post and looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name='Author')
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Titel')
   text = HTMLField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Erstellungsdatum')
   published = models.BooleanField(blank=True, verbose_name='Veröffentlichung')
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Artikel'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Artikels'
       ordering = ['-created_date']

   def publish(self):
       self.published = True
       self.save()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

as you can see, i made some fields `blank=True`.

The migration/sql Django is now performing looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "blog_post" RENAME TO "blog_post__old";
CREATE TABLE "blog_post" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"published" bool NOT NULL, "title" varchar(200) NOT NULL, "text" text NOT 
NULL, "created_date" datetime NOT NULL, "author_id" integer NOT NULL 
REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"));
INSERT INTO "blog_post" ("id", "title", "text", "created_date", "author_id", 
"published") SELECT "id", "title", "text", "created_date", "author_id", 
"published" FROM "blog_post__old";
DROP TABLE "blog_post__old";
CREATE INDEX "blog_post_author_id_dd7a8485" ON "blog_post" ("author_id");
COMMIT;
```

It just ignores the blank-values and makes every field NOT NULL.
i saw this also in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139021/django-model-and-sqlite-db-creation-bug)

The problem is, that if i implement the form in the template this field is "required" input, so the form cannot be submitted if the checkbox is unchecked.

Thanks in advance!

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    text = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30, 'class': 'materialize-textarea'}))
    published = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'published', 'text', 'tags')
```

template

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content_block %}
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Edit Post</h1>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">save</i>Speichern</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BooleanField` can store `True` or `False`, so having `NOT NULL` isn't a problem.

If you really want to allow `null` for a field, then you need `null=True`. This is a separate option from `blank=True` which you already have.

You shouldn't need to override the boolean field in your model form, since it is already a checkbox. However, if you do override it, then you need to set `required=False` if you want the field to be optional.

```
published = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), required=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that it adds "required" to my form field. Thats the problem. I will alter my question so that it will be more clear.

Comment: That's a problem in your form, not your model.

Comment: you were right, overwriting was the problem, thanks a lot! I was confused with the null=True and blaank=True in sql and thought it was a problem with the model!

Answer (score 0):

```
published = models.BooleanField(blank=True, verbose_name='Veröffentlichung')
```

source refer the docs [django model references](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/)

> Note that this is different than null. null is purely
>   database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has
>   blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a
>   field has blank=False, the field will be required.

In your forms

```
published = forms.BooleanField(required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
```

Source [Requred filed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957875/7261317)

Hope its working

Comment: Yes, thats the reason, why i made few fields blank=True, so the "required" status wont be set on these. But somehow those fields are required nevertheless.

Comment: can you add your form